# Mysql stored procedure if count is never null

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I got a table that is being updated every 5 Minutes by a Script Call, triggered by a http request. The table looks like this

```
MariaDB > select host_id, ping_eu, disk_usage,insert_time from sequencial_host;
+---------+---------+-------------+---------------------+
| host_id | ping    | disk_usage  | insert_time         |
+---------+---------+-------------+---------------------+
|       1 |   35.60 | 10329416704 | 2016-01-20 20:47:51 |
|       2 |   36.57 |  2902848512 | 2016-01-20 20:48:06 |
+---------+---------+-------------+---------------------+
```

I want to prevent a mess in case the script runs amok or any malicious intent by calling a stored procedure that allows inserting if the last insert_time was at least 4,5 Minutes ago. (30 second script built in time out, so more a less accurate).
I built this Procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `update_table`(
IN host_id_a int(11),
IN insert_time timestamp,
IN disk_usage bigint(20) ,
IN ping decimal(10,2)
BEGIN
DECLARE count INT;
SELECT count(insert_time) INTO count FROM db.sequencial_host WHERE insert_time > (NOW() - INTERVAL 270 SECOND) AND host_id = host_id_a ORDER BY insert_time DESC LIMIT 1;

IF count < 1 THEN 
    INSERT INTO db.sequencial_host ( `host_id`,`insert_time`,`disk_usage`,`ping`) 
    VALUES( host_id_a, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, disk_usage, ping);
END IF;
END
```

If I leave away the If clause, the Insert Statements work by calling the procedure and the Select Query also works for itself if executed in the shell.
I am using MariaDB 5.5.46-1ubuntu0.14.04.2.

I nearly tried any combination of IF count = 0, IF count IS NULL, IF (SELECT ..) IS NULL.

Could anybody take look?
With kind regards Joey

**EDIT:**

```
MariaDB [tempdb]> SELECT count(*) FROM tempdb.sequencial_host WHERE insert_time > (NOW() - INTERVAL 270 SECOND) AND host_id = 1 ORDER BY insert_time DESC LIMIT 1;
+--------------------+
| count(insert_time) |
+--------------------+
|                  0 |
+--------------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)

MariaDB [tempdb]> SELECT count(*) FROM tempdb.sequencial_host WHERE insert_time > (NOW() - INTERVAL 2 HOUR) AND host_id = 1 ORDER BY insert_time DESC LIMIT 1;
+--------------------+
| count(insert_time) |
+--------------------+
|                  1 |
+--------------------+
```

**Edit 2:**
Pastebin containing all relevant database information in complete. [pastebin.com/99eEDLy4](http://pastebin.com/99eEDLy4)

**Edit 3:**
If I change it to cnt = 1 I can spam the query and it fills everything, but only if there is data in the table. With a freshly truncated one I need to set it to 0 to get values in there.

Comment: perhaps the engine is getting confused on count the fxn vs count the variable.  if you use cnt instead of count.... does it work?

Comment: Sadly not. Should I try another SQL Server?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by another SQL server.  But I do believe I've isolated the problem down to count(insert_time) when no records are returned.  this will return a null value when you need to guarantee a numeric value  this can be done by using count(*) instead of count(insert_time)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a bug, it's a feature.

Inside of a Stored Procedure Select Exists returns 1 when there is data in the table and null if there is no, when the query is written like that (**without specific table set in the where clause**):
`SELECT EXISTS (SELECT * INTO count FROM db.sequencial_host WHERE insert_time > (NOW() - INTERVAL 270 SECOND) AND host_id = host_id_a ORDER BY insert_time DESC LIMIT 1)`;

If you append the table to the host id it works as expected. Even counts return the expected value. `SELECT EXISTS (SELECT * INTO count FROM db.sequencial_host WHERE insert_time > (NOW() - INTERVAL 270 SECOND) AND sequencial_host.host_id = host_id_a ORDER BY insert_time DESC LIMIT 1)`;

Answer (score 0):

count cant never < 0 . count is everytime a positive number between 0 and n. So

```
IF count < 0 THEN
```

never works

change it to

```
 IF count > 0 THEN
```

Answer (score 0):

Count on a column that is or has null, will only return count of those values which are not null. If all column values are null then null is returned.

In this case your where clause is ensuring no records return thus all column values for `insert_Time` will be null; thus null is returned.  However, if you had multiple records without null `insert_time`; then the count would represent those records without a null `insert_time`.

I think you want `count(*)` instead of `count(insert_time)` to ensure 0 is returned when no records are found.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `update_table`(
IN host_id_a int(11),
IN insert_time timestamp,
IN disk_usage bigint(20) ,
IN ping decimal(10,2))
BEGIN
DECLARE count INT;
SELECT count(*) INTO count FROM db.sequencial_host WHERE insert_time > (NOW() - INTERVAL 270 SECOND) AND host_id = host_id_a ORDER BY insert_time DESC LIMIT 1;

IF count < 1 THEN 
    INSERT INTO db.sequencial_host ( `host_id`,`insert_time`,`disk_usage`,`ping`) 
    VALUES( host_id_a, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, disk_usage, ping);
END IF;
END
```

Comment: That's also not the solution unfortunately.
I've prepared a pastebin containing the whole database information and two data samples. http://pastebin.com/99eEDLy4
I'd be happy if you could take a look.

Comment: If you just run: `SELECT count(*) FROM db.sequencial_host WHERE insert_time > (NOW() - INTERVAL 270 SECOND) AND host_id = host_id_a ORDER BY insert_time DESC LIMIT 1;` substituting the host_ID_A for the correct value what result do you get?

Comment: I've done it and edited the Main Question. The Results are as expected.
I havealso tried another server with mariadb-server-10.1. The same behavior. :/

Comment: I'm at a loss now.  All of the things I thought could be impacted here count count(*) vs count(insert_Time) have been accounted for.